# Cancelling Multiple ASIHTTPRequest's

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTP request in my app where i am firing multiple request at a time. I want to cancel all the pending requests if any fails to get data. I am not using operation queue as im sending requests from a table view on tableview scroll. How to cancel rest pending requests without affecting the successfully completed requests? 
even if you are not using NSOperationQueue or ASIHTTPOperationQueue.

Comment: You ultimately have to keep track of all the requests you are creating, better to use ASINetworkQueue, or if you don't want store all requests into an Array and cancel from that array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about canceling asynchronous `ASIHTTPRequest`?

To cancel an asynchronous request i.e. a request that was started with `[request startAsynchronous]` call `[request cancel]`.

Btw, by canceling a request `ASIHTTPRequest` treats it as an error and will call your delegate's failure method. If you do not want this behaviour, set your delegate to nil before calling cancel, or use the `clearDelegatesAndCancel` method instead. like so -

```
// Cancels an asynchronous request
[request cancel]

// Cancels an asynchronous request, clearing all delegates and blocks first
[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
```

But since you are talking about multiple requests, I would suggest you use a queue. Canceling requests could then be done in one shot using `[queue cancelAllOperations];`.